# get value from a column if the point is higher than a specific amount

Tags: php, mysql

Okay here's my table structure ,

Name: reward
structure: title , point , hasimg , imgurl

I want to do is , get the title and imgurl(if hasimg=1) when user has points equal to/more than a specific amount.

Here's an example.
the reward table is filled with these values(according to above sequence):
*1st row: ace , 1000 , 1 , http://imglink.com

2nd row: elite , 2000 , 0 , none

3rd row: pro , 3000 , 1 , http://imglink.com*

A user has **3258** points , which is **more than 3000** , so he will have the title "pro".
So how can i use mysql query to select the "pro" and the imgurl(because hasimg=1) and store them in php variables?
if a user has **2450** points , which is **more than 2000** , so he will have the title "2000" , however , it only gets the title but not get the imgurl as hasimg=0.

And how can i make sure the query dosent select 1000 and 2000 as 3000 is more than them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need the highest point record in table that is less than (or equal to) the userPoints
You can use sql query like the following

```
select * from rewards where point <= 2300 order by point desc limit 1
```

once you have the row you can check whether image bit is set and based on that show image or not.

Comment: as form your query , point < userPoints , if my points is 2300 , it should select 2000 point row , but < is smaller than , will it select the correct row?

Comment: btw its <= so that it selects smaller and equal to. btw thanks.